# Why is this code not compiling

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to write a makeshift renderer for the tutorials on
[this site](http://www.learnopengl.com). I have two classes SceneObject and RenderComponent. A SceneObject should contain a RenderComponent which should then draw the SceneObject. This is the code:

SceneObject.h

```
#ifndef _SCENE_OBJECT_H
#define _SCENE_OBJECT_H

#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "..\headers\shader.h"
#include "..\headers\rendercomponent.h"

class SceneObject {
private:
    glm::vec3 position;
    float *vertices;
    RenderComponent* renderComponent;
    std::vector<Shader> shaders;
public:
    SceneObject(glm::vec3, GLfloat*);
    ~SceneObject();
    bool init();
    RenderComponent& getRenderComponent() const;
};

#endif
```

SceneObject.cpp

```
#include "..\headers\sceneobject.h"

SceneObject::SceneObject(glm::vec3 pos, GLfloat* objectVertices) {
    this->position = pos;
    this->vertices = objectVertices;
    renderComponent = new RenderComponent(*this);
}

SceneObject::~SceneObject() {}

RenderComponent& SceneObject::getRenderComponent() const {
    return *renderComponent;
}

bool SceneObject::init() {
    if (!renderComponent->initialize()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

RenderComponent.h

```
#ifndef _RENDER_COMPONENT_H
#define _RENDER_COMPONENT_H

#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "../headers/sceneobject.h"

class RenderComponent {
    SceneObject &sceneObject;
public:
    RenderComponent(SceneObject&);
    RenderComponent(const RenderComponent&);
    bool initialize();
    void draw();

    SceneObject& getSceneObject() const;
};

#endif
```

RenderComponent.cpp

```
#include "..\headers\rendercomponent.h"

RenderComponent::RenderComponent(SceneObject& obj)
    :sceneObject(obj){}

RenderComponent::RenderComponent(const RenderComponent& ref)
    : sceneObject(ref.getSceneObject()){}

bool RenderComponent::initialize() {}

void RenderComponent::draw() {}

SceneObject& RenderComponent::getSceneObject() const {
    return sceneObject;
}
```

The following errors are produced.

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   syntax error: identifier 'SceneObject'  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   
Error   C2664   'RenderComponent::RenderComponent(const RenderComponent &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'SceneObject' to 'const RenderComponent &'  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'SceneObject'  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

From what i understand, the compiler is saying that SceneObject is not a type. I think this where the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `sceneobject.h` including `rendercomponent.h` and `rendercomponent.h` including `sceneobject.h`.  With the include guards one of them doesn't know about the classes defined in the other header.

Remove the include from one or both headers and just forward declare the class(es) instead.

Comment: I forgot what I disliked about C++ until now.